# Magento 2 Cybersource - MasterCard throws Transaction Declined error

Tags: magento2, cybersource

We are using Magento Commerce 2.3.5 with the Cybersource payment method. VISA, American Express, Discover cards are working fine. But the Mastercard throws "Transaction Declined. Please try again" error on Checkout. While checking the payment response, it has a field called "invalid-field": "card_type". But the card_type value has sent as'002'. Not sure why it's not working only for MasterCard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Was a Configuration Issue**

The issue was we didnt select the Currency(USD) for the Master Card in Cybersource dashboard. Adding the Currency fixed the issue.